# Listen in WhatsApp for click on a number and proposal my react native app as opener

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I created a react native event app with [expo](https://docs.expo.dev/). Useres can create events and invite friends by WhatsApp and more. Now I need to improve the user experience.

1. If I send a WhatsApp Message including a number. The number is highlighted.
   [image: Message]
2. On click the number, there is shown apps that can handle a number.

[image: Opener]

Two questions:

a) How can I access the proposal window to show my own app as an alternative to open on my device?

b) How can I handle it in my app, if a user choose my app?

Comment: You can achieve this with Universal Linking but only work with URL - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#universaldeep-links-without-a-custom-scheme but I don't guarantee that it will work  with telephone number

Comment: oh. i do not expect this. I give it a try later and write some feedback asap.

Comment: Ping me anytime if you need some help

Comment: hey @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel do you know the sheme to listen for numbers? This is the 'default' in every tuorial I found on web: `"data": [
      {
        "scheme": "https",
        "host": "*.myapp.io",
        "pathPrefix": "/records"
      }
    ],` I need to listgen to numbers, not to a URL.

Comment: Try `scheme:"tel"` and `host:"*"`